# Can't get document.createElement to work

Tags: javascript, html, dom, twitter

I was working on a 'Twitter verified faker'.

I made this code (to paste in your url when you're on a twitter profile):

```
javascript:var%20VERIFIEDFAKER='2.0';var%20s%20=%20document.createElement('script');s.type='text/javascript';document.body.appendChild(s);s.src='http://evertdespiegeleer.eu5.org/fakeit.js';void(0);
```

But for some reason it fails. When I add these tags manually (like it's in `http://evertdespiegeleer.eu5.org/fakeit.js`) to the twitter profile it works.

What's the problem here?

This is the code on `evertdespegeleer.eu5.org/fakeit.js`:

```
var newspan = document.createElement("span");
newspan.class = "visuallyhidden";
var newspann = document.createElement("span");
newspann.class = "icon verified verified-large-border";
var newslink = document.createElement("a");
newslink.href = "/help/verified";
newslink.class = "verified-link js-tooltip";
newslink.data-placement = "right";
newslink.data-original-title = "Verified account";
newslink.appendChild(newspann);
newspann.appendChild(newspan);
document.getElementsByTagName("h1").appendChild(newslink);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. *to paste in your url when you're on a twitter profile* — For security reasons (at least some) browsers have removed the ability to run JavaScript through the address bar. For them you will need to use the JavaScript console or a bookmarklet instead.
2. Class names are assigned to elements via the `className` property, not the `class` property.
3. Identifiers cannot include `-` characters. If you want to set a `data-*` attribute, use the `setAttribute` method.
4. `getElementsByTagName` returns a NodeList (which is like an Array that contains Elements). You can't call `appendChild` on it, you have to call `appendChild` on an Element.